# Monitoring AJAX heavy Web Application using Nagios

Tags: web-services, monitoring, nagios

We have a (AJAX heavy) web application hosted in cloud across servers and we need to monitor the availability of this service. Requires logging in to the application with a username-password, perform some searches as that user etc.

Since we plan to use Nagios for some other monitoring tasks, we decided to use Nagios for web application monitoring too.

I came across three such solutions:

1. Webinject: I don't feel like using this. Project not under active development. It was last released in Jan 2006. I can't see any support/help available. Also I suspect how will it behave with Ajax.
2. Cucumber-Nagios:
   I tried using this. It involves many Ruby components and found that you have to have in-depth knowledge of Ruby platform to make all these components work together. I am not a Ruby guy and having tough time making all these components work together. Also even this project is not under active development and I don't see support/help options available. I posted a bug 4 days back and don't see any response yet.
3. Selenium plugin for Nagios: Haven't tried it yet. Will try now.

Any more solutions available?

Also, since I don't see any good actively developed solutions for monitoring web applications using Nagios, I suspect if it's really a good approach to use Nagios for this? If not, what alternatives do I have? In short what is the best approach to monitor web applications availability?

**Edit 1:** We can't afford the Nagios XI paid version and will prefer open source solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> If not, what alternatives do I have?

Although Nagios was one of options that we've considered, we've chosen [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org) for monitoring purposes. Rationale for our decision is that OpenNMS is highly reliable and configurable free open-source tool and additionally, most of our applications are Java-based; OpenNMS offers integration with JMX. However, bear in mind that if you're demanding very complex tests for your Web site maybe it's better to look elsewhere. OpenNMS can be set to check for HTTP status codes etc., but if you're looking for complex scenarios take a look at:

- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) (we're using it mainly during the testing phase)
- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) (can be well used even in production phase)